# UIAlertController presenting and dismissing based on internet connection crashes when on cellular data

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui, swift3

I have a strange crash on my app, I created a `NWPathMonitor` `pathUpdateHandler` to check for network connection.
Inside the `pathUpdateHandler`, I added two conditional statements based on the network satisfied on unsatisfied, which when the internet disconnects a UIAlertController will show on the screen and when is connected back again it would disappear the alert.

The problem is I have a strange crash when testing this, if I try to reconnect the app via WI-FI it is fine, but when I try to reconnect the app via cellular data, it says an error that I have tried to add a view modally.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    
    let networkQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "InternetConnectionMonitor")
    var textInternet : Bool = true
    var internetPopUp : UIAlertController!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.internetPopUp = UIAlertController(title: "Internet Connection", message: "Currently, the device is not connected to Internet, as soon as will be connected the alert will dissapear.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        startMonitoring()
    }
    
    //check internet connection
    func startMonitoring(){
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = {  pathUpdateHandler in
            if  pathUpdateHandler.status == .satisfied{
                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    //dismissed if it is not dismissing
                    self.textInternet = true
                    self.pop()
                }            
            }
            else {
                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    //present if its not already presenting
                    self.textInternet = false
                    self.pop()        
                }
            }
        }
        
        monitor.start(queue: networkQueue)
    }
    
    func pop(){
        if self.textInternet == true {
            self.popDownAlert()
        } else {
            self.popUpAlert()
        }
    }
         
    //func popUp Alert
    func popUpAlert(){
        if !self.internetPopUp.isBeingPresented{
            self.present(self.internetPopUp, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    //func popDown Alert
    func popDownAlert() {
        if !self.internetPopUp.isBeingDismissed{
            self.internetPopUp.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not getting what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: That's simply because you are doing it under `viewDidLoad`.  That's the violation of El Tomato Rule 21.

Comment: @ELTomato could you please explain why it is wrong, and what solution do I have?

Comment: @ElTomato could you please explain why it is wrong, and what solutions do I have?

Comment: Tell us what the purpose of `viewDidLoad` is.  If you knew the answer, you wouldn't show `UIAlertController` inside `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @ElTomato Im not sure but I guess the viewdidLoad does stuff exactly after the main view is loaded, If im wrong could you please help me understand it better. By the way, im not getting it in my post, the uialert is instantiated in the viewDidAppear, which I guess calls everything as soon as the view have appeared. So I don't get it why you are telling me that the problem is because im doing it in the viewDidLoad, when actually in my post is in the ViewDidAppear.

Comment: If you format your code properly, removing irrelevant lines, so that I can run it, I'll take another look.

Comment: When you present `UIAlertController` in popUpAlert, delay the execution by 0.25 with `DispatchQueue` like DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) { }

Comment: @ElTomato now im gonna try it, may I ask what was the problem, and why the solution DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) { } . I would like to understand what's happening under the hood.

Comment: @ElTomato tried but still dont works, still it crashes.

Comment: If that doesn't work, your crash is caused by somehing else other than `UIAlertController`.